# Esp32 BLE repeater

Tags: esp32, bluetooth-low-energy

I am using ESP32-S3 custom development board for my project.
I want to implement BLE repeater behavior in my project.

The idea is I have three ESP32-S3 boards.One as a server other as a receiver if any obstacle comes in between these two or if the distance is too long I will place another esp32-s3 in the middle .So, it should acts as a repeater like it needs to receive data from server and it should send that data to client.
I am using arduino IDE with NIMBLE stack.I checked in the google also I didn't find any source to implement the repeater concept.

Is it possible to use one ESP32-S3 board as repeater(both server and client at a time so it will receive data from server as a client and it will act as a server to send date other esp32-s3 client board).

Can you please suggest me how to implement it. Please share the links for reference if it is possible to implement.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.